# Right_aws get .tar.gz from S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rake

I am writing a rake task to restore a database from a backup file that is a .tar.gz stored in S3.

Step 1, download file from S3, right? I am using [right_aws's S3Interface](http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/right_aws_gem_doc/classes/RightAws/S3Interface.html#M000198). 
I tried the simple get which returns the file content in :object.

```
obj = s3.get(s3_config[:s3_bucket], s3_file_name)
temp_file.write obj[:object]
```

Error:
    rake aborted!
"\x8B" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I saw some posts about using GzipWriter and String#unpack but couldn't successfully apply them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Opening the file with 'wb' flags did the trick.

```
  temp_file = File.new(File.join(tmp_dir, 'temp.tar.gz'), 'wb')
  obj = s3.get(s3_config[:s3_bucket], s3_file_name)
  temp_file.write obj[:object]
  temp_file.close
```

Comment: Glad that helped someone :)